# Import "dirty" .xls with read.xls

Tags: r, excel, import

I would like to import a `.xls` file from the Internet using `read.xls`. I already adjusted the lines to skip and the encoding, but it still doesn't work!
Any ideas on this? Is the Excel file to "dirty"?

```
library("gdata")
read.xls("http://www.gsi-berlin.info/redirectA.asp?filename=TS1200199029201312.xls", 
         sheet=2, skip=5, fileEncoding="utf8")
```

Comment: The importation does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

Try using `readxl` instead.  This seems to work much better.

```
library(readxl)

# Need to download the file first
df <- read_excel("/.../TS1200199029201312.xls", sheet=2, skip=5)
```

`head(df)`

```
  01011101            Stülerstr. 0.130378
1 01011102     Großer Tiergarten        x
2 01011103            Lützowstr. 0.451560
3 01011104            Körnerstr. 0.191847
4 01011105  Nördl. Landwehrkanal        x
5 01011201           Wilhelmstr.        .
6 01011202 Unter den Linden Nord        x
```

Comment: The first data line of the `.xls` is missing, and skip=4 won't fix it. Besides, the encoding is broken and adding file.encoding="utf8" makes the command erroneous again...mhhh...

Comment: @Gui_struggling_with_R See my edit.  Try using `readxls` instead as it needs less arguments to get what you want, but you've got to download the file first.  Hope this helps